# Dilation of Real Valued Lebesgue Integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Below is a statement of a question I've been struggle to understand; I also attached a proof below the statement. I feel that it's a very incomplete and inaccurate proof right off the bat.  If anyone can possible hint at how to adjust my first case, the rest will follow from that. However, as written, I'm not comfortable saying I've satisfied the result.

The question is:

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be integrable and $a \neq 0$. Then $g(x)=f(ax)$ is integrable and $\int f = |a| \int g$.

We break this proof into cases, each of which depends on how $f$ is defined.

(i) Suppose that $f(x) = \chi_A(x)$, where $A$ is some measurable set of finite measure. Then 
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
1, &\text{if } ax \in A\\
0, &\text{if } ax \not \in A.
\end{cases}
$$
Then
\begin{align*}
\int |g(x)| &= \int |f(ax)|\\
&= \int \begin{cases}
1, &\text{if } ax \in A\\
0, &\text{if } ax \not \in A.
\end{cases}\\
&= \underbrace{ \int \frac{1}{|a|} \begin{cases}
1, &\text{if } x \in A\\
0, &\text{if } x \not \in A.
\end{cases}}_{\text{ This line is my main concern}}\\
&= \frac{1}{|a|} \int f,
\end{align*}
verifying the result for the first case.

(ii) Suppose that $f$ is a nonnegative, integrable simple function with canonical representation given by $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} e_i \chi_{E_i}$. Then 
\begin{align*}
\int |g(x)| &+ \int |f(ax)|\\
&= \int \sum_{i=0}^n e_i \chi_{E_i}\\
&= e_o \int \begin{cases}
1, &\text{if } ax \in E_0\\
0, &\text{if } ax \not \in E_0.
\end{cases} + \cdots + e_n \int \begin{cases}
1, &\text{if } ax \in E_n\\
0, &\text{if } ax \not \in E_n.
\end{cases}\\
&= \frac{e_o}{|a|} \int \begin{cases}
1, &\text{if } x \in E_0\\
0, &\text{if } x \not \in E_0.
\end{cases} + \cdots + \frac{e_n}{|a|} \int \begin{cases}
1, &\text{if } x \in E_n\\
0, &\text{if } x \not \in E_n.
\end{cases}\\
&= \frac{1}{|a|} \sum_{i=0}^{n} e_i m(E_i) = \frac{1}{|a|} \int f,
\end{align*}
verifying the result for this case.

(iii) For this case, suppose that $f$ is an arbitrary nonnegative integrable function. Then, there exist a sequence of nonnegative, integrable simple functions $(\varphi_n)$, whose terms have canonical representation $\varphi(x) = \sum_{i=0}^m e_i \chi_{E_i}$, increasing pointwise everywhere to $f$. Then 
$$
\int |g(x)| = \int |f(ax)| = \int f(ax) = \int \lim_{n \to \infty} \varphi_n(ax).
$$
With how we've defined the sequence, we may apply the Monotone Convergence Theorem the the fine equality to get 
$$
\int \lim_{n \to \infty} \varphi_n(ax) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int \varphi_n(ax) = \frac{1}{|a|}  \lim_{n \to \infty} \int \varphi_{n}(x),
$$
where the last equality holds from the preceding case. With a second application of the Monotone Convergence Theorem, we see that 
$$
\int |g(x)| =\frac{1}{|a|}  \lim_{n \to \infty} \int \varphi_{n}(x) = \frac{1}{|a|}   \int \lim_{n \to \infty} \varphi_{n}(x) = \frac{1}{|a|} \int f,
$$
completing this case.

(iv) Finally, let $f$ be any integrable function. Then we can reduce to case two by writing $f = f^+-f^-$, the difference of its positive and negative parts, which is the different of nonnegative integrable function, completing the proof.

Comment: Note that $\chi_A(ax) = \begin{cases} 1 & ax\in A \\ 0 & ax\not\in A\end{cases}$ but then this is the same as $\chi_{A/a}(x)$. By virtue of the Lebesgue measure, $\lambda(A/a)$ is just $\lambda(A)/a$.

Comment: Thank you. So this is really correct then? It just felt like cheating to me.

Comment: I think you're good.

Comment: It is correct, but given the claim you want to prove it is not a good step. Essentially, you are using the result for proving the result. To justify the step, you need to tell us how you defined the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Sorry, I did skip out on that detail. We define a $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ to be measurable if there exist closed set $F$ and and open set $G$ with $F \subset A \subset G$ such that, given any $\epsilon > 0$, $m(G \setminus F) < \epsilon$.  From here, we notice that, if $A$ is measurable and $r \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, then $m(rA) = |r|m(A)$, where $rA = \{ ra \colon a \in A\}$. Does this finish it off?

Comment: @m2271r: Yes, if you know $m(rA) = |r| m(A)$, this completes the argument. Note though that your comments still does not really answer how the Lebesgue measure is defined, since you need to know how $m$ is defined on open sets. But you know at least how it is defined on intervals (I guess?) and on intervals, the desired relation $m(rA) = |r| m(A)$ (in dimension 1) is clear. It is then not too hard to lift this to all measurable sets.

Comment: I've really only discussed Lebesgue Measure on the line, but I've done some additional reading on my own. However, I suppose if you want to talk about an arbitrary subset of $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, for $n$ a positive integer, then the Lebesgue Outer measure of this set would be given by $m^{*}(E) = \inf \{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} V(I_n) \colon E \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n \}$, where the $I_n$ are $n-$dimensional closed rectangle. Then, for the correspondence between $m^{*}$ and $m$, see the definition (last comment). I hope this helps? I'm not really sure what you're asking. @PhoemueX